# Output filtering with sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, mpc

I need filter this mpc output:

```
Burzum - Budstikken
[playing] #6/7   5:03/10:10 (49%)
volume: 60%   repeat: off   random: on    single: off   consume: offere
```

To this:

```
5:03
```

Using sed.

Comment: What if duration is less than 60 secs or greater than 59:59?

Comment: mpc tag here is not a minimalist command line interface to MPD. You should remove this tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
mpc (...) | 
sed -nr '/^\[playing/s@.* ([0-9]+:[0-9]+)/.*@\1@p'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sed -r '/playing/!d; s%.*([0-9]+:[0-9]+)/.*%\1%'
```